# $\int_C (x+2y)dx+(x-y)dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the following line integral: 
$$\int_C (x+2y)\mathrm{d}x +(x-y)\mathrm{d}y$$ 
where C: $x=2\cos t, y=4\sin t, 0\leq t\leq (\pi/4)$
Since the parameterization is given I express everything in terms of t:
$$\int_C (2\cos t + 8\sin t)(-2\sin t) dt+(2\cos t -4\sin t)4\cos t dt$$ where $\mathrm{d}x=-2\sin t dt  \mathrm{d}y=4\cos t dt$
After simplifying the integral I come up with: $$\int_0^{\pi/4} (-20\sin t \cos t -16(\sin t)^2+8(\cos t)^2)\mathrm{d}t$$ 
My question involves the setup of the line integral and not the evaluation, this evaluates to $1-\pi$ but the solution given is $-9/2-\pi$ I can't seem to see where I went wrong in the setup.

Comment: Pretty sure you mean "$(-2 \sin t) dt$".

Comment: ...  or perhaps a different pair of grouping symbols ...

Comment: http://www.math.drexel.edu/~jsa33/291Su201245/Practice/Line_Integrals_Ans.pdf

Comment: Here is the link, problem 5 a)

Answer (score 1):

Your setup and answer, both are correct. [link to integral's page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20(2%5Ccos%20t%20%2B%208%5Csin%20t)(-2%5Csin%20t)%20%2B(2%5Ccos%20t%20-4%5Csin%20t)4%5Ccos%20t%20from%200%20to%20(pi%2F4))

There is most probably a typo in the question itself.